# VB.NET How to control multiple controls with similar procedures

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm using the following code:

```
Private Sub lblTest_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles lblTest.MouseDown
    startx = MousePosition.X
    starty = MousePosition.Y
    mdown = True
    valx = False
    valy = False
End Sub


Private Sub Main_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove

End Sub

Private Sub lblTest_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles lblTest.MouseMove
    Dim endx As Integer
    Dim endy As Integer

    'Check if mouse=down
    If mdown = True Then
        endx = (MousePosition.X - Me.Left)
        endy = (MousePosition.Y - Me.Top)

        If valy = False Then
            starty = endy - sender.top
            valy = True
        End If
        If valx = False Then
            startx = endx - sender.left
            valx = True
        End If
        sender.left = endx - startx
        sender.top = endy - starty


    End If
End Sub

Private Sub lblTest_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles lblTest.MouseUp
    mdown = False
    valx = False
    valy = False

End Sub
```

What this does is allows me to move labels around with the mouse during runtime.  What I'd like to be able to do is move multiple labels around with similar code, but obviously I don't want to write a procedure for each label control.  That is I want to move lblTest to lblTest(1+n).  The number of labels I plan on moving will be fluid (for reasons too boring to detail).

Too much of a vb novice to even know if this is something I can do or am I just stuck with a whole lot of copy/paste in my future?

Comment: Using inheritance is an essential strategy in Winforms.  Add a class to your project, say Class MyLabel: Inherits Label.  Override the OnMouseDown and OnMouseMove methods.  Build > Build and the new control is added to the top of the toolbox.  Drop as many as you need on the form, they all behave the same without any extra code.

Comment: Thanks Hans!  That's good stuff to know.  I like it.

Comment: Append the additional controls to the Handles clause of the event. `Handles lblTest.MouseUp, LabelTest2.MouseUp, LabelTest3.MouseUP"

Comment: Write a procedure for one of the labels. Then go to the designer. Choose another label and in the Properties window click the lightning bolt. Select the Event you need and click the little drop down arrow. Your should see the Event procedure you just wrote in the code window. Select that event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop for each Label control in your form and add the same event handlers to them:

Example:

```
For Each lab As Label In Controls
    If (TypeOf lab Is Label) Then
         AddHandler lab.MouseMove, AddressOf Your_MouseMove
         AddHandler lab.MouseDown, AddressOf Your_MouseDown
         AddHandler lab.MouseUp, AddressOf Your_MouseUp
    End If
Next

Private Sub Your_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    ' Mouse up code
End Sub

Private Sub Your_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    'Mouse Down code
End Sub

Private Sub Your_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
    Dim endx As Integer
    Dim endy As Integer

    'Check if mouse=down
    If mdown = True Then
        endx = (MousePosition.X - Me.Left)
        endy = (MousePosition.Y - Me.Top)

        If valy = False Then
            starty = endy - sender.top
            valy = True
        End If
        If valx = False Then
            startx = endx - sender.left
            valx = True
        End If
        sender.left = endx - startx
        sender.top = endy - starty
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: A little clarification if you don't mind... cControl.MouseMove is throwing error saying MouseMove is not an event of object.  Which makes a bit of sense I think, but I'm in over my head on this one.  And I'd need to add an event handler for mousedown and mouseup as well, but these also throw errors about not being an event of the object.

Comment: @user10105356 For me it's working well, i tried the code. You can also add hander for every event you need. I updated the answer adding the other event handlers.

Comment: @user10105356  user Hans Passant gave you also a good solution, check also at his approach